# Django import export keep reading blank line

Tags: django, django-import-export

I'm using [`django-import-export`](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). But sometimes I got an error when importing `xlsx` file. The error is simple actually. It keeps reading the blank row so it generates an error.

For example, in my `xlsx` file, there are only two rows (one for the table header and one for the data). I don't know why but it also read the second and the third row even though there is no data in it.

The error is something like this:

```
Line number: 2 - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'
None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None
```

Of course, the data is all `None`, because I only want to import only one data so the second row is empty.

How to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: possibly there are blank hidden rows in your Excel.  If you delete these rows it should import ok.